# jq: error: syntax error, unexpected if, while checking for a object to be present and if not the adding default value

Tags: json, shell, kubernetes, jq, kubectl

Getting the error

```
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected if (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level> while parsing kubernetes kubectl command,
kubectl get pv -o=json | jq -c '.items[] | {name: .metadata.name, claimName: .spec | if has("claimRef") then .claimRef.name else empty end }'
```

Trying to get the PV's which have PVC and if there are no PVC can be null of empty.
For it uilding a map of name and their respective PVC if there otherwise empty or null.

Below is a sample input to the jq command or the out put of the command `kubectl get pv -o=json`

```
{
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "items": [{
            "apiVersion": "v1",
            "kind": "PersistentVolume",
            "metadata": {
                "annotations": {
                    "meta.helm.sh/release-name": "",
                    "meta.helm.sh/release-namespace": ""
                },
                "creationTimestamp": "",
                "finalizers": [
                    ""
                ],
                "labels": {
                    "app.kubernetes.io/managed-by": ""
                },
                "name": "",
                "resourceVersion": "",
                "uid": ""
            },
            "spec": {
                "accessModes": [
                    "ReadWriteMany"
                ],
                "capacity": {
                    "storage": ""
                },
                "claimRef": {
                    "apiVersion": "",
                    "kind": "",
                    "name": "",
                    "namespace": "",
                    "resourceVersion": "",
                    "uid": ""
                },
                "csi": {
                    "driver": "",
                    "volumeHandle": ""
                },
                "persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy": "",
                "volumeMode": ""
            },
            "status": {
                "phase": ""
            }
        },
        {
            "apiVersion": "v1",
            "kind": "PersistentVolume",
            "metadata": {
                "annotations": {
                    "meta.helm.sh/release-name": "",
                    "meta.helm.sh/release-namespace": ""
                },
                "creationTimestamp": "",
                "finalizers": [
                    ""
                ],
                "labels": {
                    "app.kubernetes.io/managed-by": ""
                },
                "name": "",
                "resourceVersion": "",
                "uid": ""
            },
            "spec": {
                "accessModes": [
                    "ReadWriteMany"
                ],
                "capacity": {
                    "storage": ""
                },
                "claimRef": {
                    "apiVersion": "",
                    "kind": "",
                    "name": "",
                    "namespace": "",
                    "resourceVersion": "",
                    "uid": ""
                },
                "csi": {
                    "driver": "",
                    "volumeHandle": ""
                },
                "persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy": "",
                "volumeMode": ""
            },
            "status": {
                "phase": ""
            }
        }
    ],
    "kind": "List",
    "metadata": {
        "resourceVersion": "",
        "selfLink": ""
    }
}
```

For data security have removed the data and only kept the keys
Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put parentheses around the value of the `claimName` field:

```
{
  name: .metadata.name,
  claimName: (.spec | if has("claimRef") then .claimRef.name else empty end)
}
```

Depending on how much you simplified your example, you may consider reducing the the `if` statement to:

```
{
  name: .metadata.name,
  claimName: (.spec.claimRef.name? // empty)
}
```

Note that in both cases not just `.claimName` but the whole object will disappear if the respective test is going to fail.

Comment: Thanks @pmf for the solution it is working now. How can have the empty object in the claimName in case .spec.claimRef is not there.

Comment: Make the `else` branch, as you say, an "empty object" which is `{}`: `{name: .metadata.name} + (.spec | if has("claimRef") then {claimName: .claimRef.name} else {} end)`.

Comment: Great @pmf, this solves things, thanks